# How to override two maps in scss

Tags: css, sass

**SCSS**

```
$colors: (
   primary:      red,
   secondary:    blue,
   accent:       #ddd,
) !default;

$colors: (
   primary:      green,
   secondary:    purple,
   black:        #000,
   white:        #fff,
);

@each $color, $value in $colors {
  .alert-#{$color} {
    color: $value;
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
.alert-primary {
     color: green;
}
 .alert-secondary {
     color: purple;
}
 .alert-black {
     color: #000;
}
 .alert-white {
     color: #fff;
}
```

I wanted to create a SASS framework something like bootstrap. Wanted to override theme colors. How can i merge these maps to get something like this? I want a simple solution.

**Expected result**

```
.alert-accent {
   color: #ddd;
}
.alert-primary {
   color: green;
}
.alert-secondary {
   color: purple;
}
.alert-black {
   color: #000;
}
.alert-white {
   color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [map-merge](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map#merge):

```
$colors: map-merge($colors, (
   primary:      green,
   secondary:    purple,
   black:        #000,
   white:        #fff
));
```

From the documentation, this function:

> Returns a new map with all the keys and values from both `$map1` and `$map2`.
>
> This can also be used to add a new value or overrwrite a value in `$map1`, by passing a single key/value pair as `$map2`.
>
> If both `$map1` and `$map2` have the same key, `$map2`’s value takes precedence.